# How can I vectorize this python for loop?

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to count the number of events with various thresholds. So I used for loop to use it as thresholds but the number of events is too many so it takes too much time.
So I want to vectorize this macro and reduce compute time. Can I get some help?

```
array_ = np.array(bin_number)

for i in range(bin_number):
    mask_1 = array_ML[:,0] > i
    masked_array = array_ML[mask_1]

    mask_2 = masked_array[:,2] == 0
    masked_array = masked_array[mask_2]

    array_[i] = masked_array.shape[0]
```

Comment: Note that vectorization isn't necessarily a magic bullet. If your arrays are large, the indexing and copying may take so much time the overhead of the for-loop is negligible.

Comment: Since `masked_array[:,2] == 0` is always the same (other than the mask), I suspect you can move this filtering outside of your loop. E.g., `temp_array = array_ML[masked_array[:, 2] == 0]`, then inside your loop, `mask1 = temp_array[:, 0] > i` etc.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. This could save some time. Thank you.

Comment: `array_ = np.array(bin_number)` -> `array_ = np.arange(bin_number)`, I take it?

Comment: Yes, it could be. And I think ```array_ = np.zeros(bin_number)``` is more like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a dedicated function in NumPy that does this for you, but otherwise, the following simplifications are likely to speed up your code significantly:

```
import numpy as np

# Create example data
array_ML = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10000, 200))
array_ML[:, 2] = np.where(array_ML[:, 2] > 500, 0, 1)

bin_number = 100
array_ = np.zeros(bin_number, dtype=int)

# filter what we can, before the loop
mask = array_ML[:, 2] == 0
temp = array_ML[mask, 0]
# Just count, by summing the condition
for i in range(bin_number):
    array_[i] = np.sum(temp > i)
```

With the above example data, my timings (using `%%time` in Jupyter notebook cells) reduce from 439 ms (original code) to 3.86 ms (code above).

Of course, the timing decreases are heavily dependent on your input data shape, distribution of data, and `bin_number`; my timings serve as an indication.

Comment: You could further speed-up the code by replacing the last loop by `array_ = np.sum(temp[:, None] > np.arange(bin_number), axis=0)`.